# python module won't recognize variables

Tags: python, function, module

brand new to Python, taking intro class.  I'm having trouble understanding how to get a module to pick up a return value from a function and use it to perform calculations.
In this example, I gather the "size" of radius of a circle from user, then the geometry module should take the size, calculate the circumference, and pass it back to the project file to be displayed.
Although, no matter what I've tried, the  "size" variable is not able to be recognized by the geometry module. "NameError: name 'size' is not defined"

Main project file:

```
import geometry

    def main():
        size, unit = getUserInput()
        displayCircleResults(geometry.circleCircum, geometry.circleArea)

    def getUserInput():
        size = float(input('Enter length of radius: '))
        unit = input('Enter unit of measure, e/g., inches: ')
        return size, unit
```

geometry.py module:

```
def main():
    radius = circleCircum(size)

def circleCircum():
    return math.pi * size**2
```

How does one get the module to accept return values from another file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't invoked the function.  A function name is followed by parentheses.  You used **circleCircum** and **circleArea** as if they are scalar attributes (variables).

Also, the variables in question are local to their packages: main and geometry.  The **size** in your main program has nothing to do with the local variable in geometry.  You have to pass the value, just as with any other function.

Moving somewhat in that direction ...

```
displayCircleResults(geometry.circleCircum(size), geometry.circleArea(size))
...
def circleCircum(size):
    return math.pi * size**2
```

I'm not quite sure how you expect geometry.main() to work, but you've given it no communication with the outside world.  **size** isn't passed in, and **radius** isn't sent anywhere.